# UWP How to set the open direction of AutoSuggestBox Suggestions?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am trying to standardize which direction an AutoSuggestBox's Suggestion List opens. UWP seems to dictate the direction based on which vertical half of the screen the box resides. If the box is in the top half of the screen the suggestion list expands below the text box. If the box is in the bottom half the suggestion list expands above the text box. However I would like the suggestion list to always expand below the text box.

It looks as though the "Placement" property on the "Popup" xaml tag may be used to do this, however that is not supported in UWP. Is there a similar property or code behind work-around I can use?

Comment: [UIElement.TransformToVisual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.transformtovisual#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_TransformToVisual_Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_) and [GeneralTransform.TransformPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.GeneralTransform#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_GeneralTransform_TransformPoint_Windows_Foundation_Point_) seems to be the alternative way to set the popup location based on a element. Maybe you can give them a try.

Comment: By the way, if you want the placement feature maybe you can send your user voice to [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform)

Comment: Thank-you very much Barry!

Comment: by the way, if you've already submitted the feature request, don't forget to share us the link. I have to track it in my internal channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the resultant code.

```
    private void autoSuggestBox_UpdateForceListDown(object sender)
    {
        var asb = sender as UIElement;
        var relativeView = asb.TransformToVisual(null);
        Point point = relativeView.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
        var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;
        ApplicationView view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
        var titleBarHeight = view.VisibleBounds.Top;
        if (point.Y > ((bounds.Height - titleBarHeight) / 2) && VerticalOffset != 400)
        {
            VerticalOffset = 400;
            IsSmallScreen = true;
        }
        else if (point.Y < ((bounds.Height - titleBarHeight) / 2))
        {
            VerticalOffset = 0;
            IsSmallScreen = false;
        }
    }
```

IsSmallScreen is used in the filter to decide if the filtered list should be reversed.